# Webpack react-native-webpack-server import 3d part library

Tags: react-native, webpack

Have this webpack config I am using react-native-webpack-server

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    'index.ios': ['./src/main.js'],
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: { stage: 0, plugins: ['./build/babelRelayPlugin'] }
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [],
};
```

When I do import

import ScrollableTabView from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';

I got

```js
ERROR in ./~/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/index.js
Module parse failed: /Users/butuzgol/Playground/watchme/node_modules/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/index.js Line 135: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       return React.cloneElement(this.props.renderTabBar(), props);
|     } else {
|       return <DefaultTabBar {...props} />;
|     }
|   },
 @ ./src/pages/dashboard.js 25:36-79
```

Also I found this issue https://github.com/mjohnston/react-native-webpack-server/issues/34 but for now I haven't found solution

Answer (score 0):

I updated regexp in exclude attr

```
exclude: /(?!node_modules\/react-native-scrollable-tab-view)node_modules/,
```